# Leafletjs Invalid GeoJSON object

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am using the following coming back from a socketio connection:

```
L.geoJson(data.streets, {
     onEachFeature: map.onEachFeature
});
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
Invalid GeoJSON object.
```

[My GeoJSON is here](http://pastebin.com/fgAFFMz6)

I've run it through several JSON/GeoJSON validating tools and they all come back as valid. It's also definitely already a json object (I tried with `JSON.parse(data.streets)`)

What am I missing? I did use a `flatProperties` option on my osmtogeojson library but as mentioned, the above code validates on all the online checks I can find.

Comment: As @FranceImage showed, the GeoJSON itself is valid.  So it must be how you are using it.  Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) showing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJson you link to is valid

See by yourself http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/pcqsne4z/

```
L.geoJson(getData(), {
    onEachFeature: handleFeature
    }
).addTo(map);

function getData() { 
return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
...
...
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [-1.0950612, 50.7902086],
                [-1.0953699, 50.790231]
            ]
        }
    }]};
}
```

You have to check what is in data.streets

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what changed by my browser stopped throwing that error today, so I'll mark this as answered. So strange and sorry for wasting your time :/